# Using Spring Factory bean pattern - no bean return null?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I am using Factory pattern in SPRING like in this example 
http://kh-yiu.blogspot.co.il/2013/04/spring-implementing-factory-pattern.html

In case that there is no bean with specific name 
I get exception org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'XXX' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean$ServiceLocatorInvocationHandler.invokeServiceLocatorMethod(ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.java:367)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean$ServiceLocatorInvocationHandler.invoke(ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.java:356)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.createManualDepositProcess(Unknown Source)
```

I get exceptions in case I try to get bean that not defined, like printStrategyFactory.getStrategy("NO_DEF").print(doc);

Is it possible in case that there is **no bean - return null ?**
Thank you !

Comment: You can decide to return null. Use a try/catch to catch Spring's exception in your factory method.

Comment: Can I overwrite the return function ?

Comment: No, I see in the example you reference that you are using Spring's `ServiceLocatorFactoryBean`. You cannot change it's behavior of throwing an exception when the lookup fails, although you can change the exception that is thrown. You need to surround the code calling the lookup with try/catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're autowiring as in the example you posted, `@Autowired(required=false)` should do the trick.

Edit: sorry for getting your question wrong at first, I just spotted the `@Autowired` annotation in the Test of the link you posted and thought of the standard solution.

Comment: the error is in case I want to get bean that not defined like printStrategyFactory.getStrategy("NO_DEF").print(doc);

Comment: but that would mean you would get a NullPointerException anyway if no bean for this strategy can be loaded even if null was returned, right?

Comment: How to prevent the exception in this case ?               PrintA4LandscapeStrategy bean = printStrategyFactory.getStrategy("NO_DEF");